# What do these numbers on a package drawing mean?

Tags: drawing

I saw this on a package drawing in a [BC847 datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC847_SER.pdf):

[image]

What do the numbers mean? They look like a date, but the SOT883 package is much more recent than 2003. (By the way, the numbers on the drawings for the other packages are "04-11-04", also palindromic. Coincidence?)

Comment: @Chu: I doubt it. None of the numbers seem to fit, and for the other three packages the numbers are the same each time, though the packages differ. Also, dimensions are given in the drawing, why repeat(?) them separately? Thanks for your thoughts, though.

Comment: Contact the supplier is my advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about EE.

Comment: @Andyaka I disagree with you, it is an image taken from a transistor datasheet. How can physical transistor package outline drawings be off-topic?

Comment: @Andyaka why is this not EE design related? Doesn't an electronics designer need to understand technical drawings of the parts he is using? By this argument an EE designer shouldn't mess with PCB fabrication tolerancing, for example.

Comment: The symbols are for the projection. Numbers look most like some kind of tolerance. Why would it matter, by the way?

Comment: @Gregory: Why it would matter? Well, if I don't know what the numbers mean I can't know if they matter, can I?

Comment: Of course! As a matter of fact, you must know what you need and filter out everything else. IMHO, of course. Otherwise you will waste precious time on reading endless datasheets.

Comment: @Andyaka (and the other voter-to-close): If you ever created a component footprint for a PCB package then you know that *everything* in a mechanical drawing is of importance. Since I didn't know what the numbers meant (that was my question!) I couldn't know if they're relevant.

Comment: I'm supportive of understanding **everything** in a datasheet. Too often something that will bite you hard is hidden in plain sight.

Answer (score 4):

It is the drawing issue date in ISO order (YY-MM-DD). It's paired with the symbol for first angle orthographic projection, so obviously belongs in a title block of a full drawing. Below is part of a title block of a more complete NXP drawing.

[image]

Edit: as confirmation see the NXP package [drawing](http://www.nxp.com/packages/SOT883.html), which bears the same April 3, 2003 date.

Edit2: The date format is specified to follow ISO order even in the ASME (U.S.) version of the GD&T standard as follows:

> ASME Y14.100, 4.28:
>   The method of specifying dates on drawings shall be
>   numerical by year-month-day for entry in the “DATE”
>   block. For example, June 10, 1989 would be indicated
>   as 1989-06-10, 89-06-10, 19890610, 890610, 1989/06/10,
>   or 89/06/10.

This is somewhat controversial (in the U.S. anyway).

Comment: +1: I think you are right. I had the same feeling. I recognized the European projection symbol (a.k.a. 1st angle projection symbol) and I was just searching for a confirmation of what meant the numbers besides it.

Comment: Yep, you are definitely right, as reported in this [NXP drawing for the SOT883 package](http://www.nxp.com/documents/outline_drawing/sot883_po.pdf). At the end you can see the same issue date as the OP has on its datasheet.

Comment: So it seems to be a date after all. But how can we explain then that the drawing of a SOT883 is dated years before that package came into being? (Or am I wrong about the SOT883's date?) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JorisGroosman maybe an update to the industry standard is referenced. You may see in the link I posted in the above comment that updates are possible.

Comment: [nagging mode on :-)] I'm not sure this is ISO format, though the order of the date's fields agrees with it. Doesn't ISO require 4 digits for the year? [nagging mode off]

Comment: @JorisGroosman I don't have a copy of the ISO version of ASME Y14.10, but I changed the answer to specify only the order (since one might assume it was referring to ISO 8601). Thanks.

Comment: @JorisGroosman as to the introduction dates, the drawing dates linked in my answer and in Lorenzo's comment both irrefutably indicate a 2003 date. Drawings could precede the part introduction (some drawing surely did!) and/or the package could have been made under a different name. Or you could be wrong, I have not looked.

Comment: @JorisGroosman As I said in a comment to the answer of jippie that date is NOT in ISO8601 format, but Sphero didn't say that. He said "ISO order", not "ISO format", so he is correct even in a "nitpicker's POV".

Comment: @Lorenzo: He changed the original word "format" to "order". Look at the edits.

Comment: @JorisGroosman Oh, well, sorry then. I didn't notice the change. Your comment was indeed spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this random other datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT04.pdf) page 9 which has some extra information with the symbols:

[image]

The taper indicates "European projection" and the numbers are simply a YY-MM-DD formatted issue date.

An alternative projection is "American projection". [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_drawing#Multiple_views_and_projections) elaborates on the differences.

Comment: Same comment as for Spehro: So it seems to be a date after all. But how can we explain then that the drawing of a SOT883 is dated years before that package came into being? (Or am I wrong about the SOT883's date?) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JorisGroosman: http://www.nxp.com/packages/SOT883.html Don't know what date you had in mind. I didn't bother, but on the products tab you could check some other parts that come in the same package, and their datasheets which will probably be dated in turn...

Comment: Just a nitpick: the date is NOT in ISO8601 format. That standard was introduced also to avoid most misunderstandings between date formats across different countries. That standard mandates a 4 digit year as it is also noted in the Wikipedia page you linked to.

Comment: @jippie: thanks for pointing out about the projection used, but that was not what my question was about (that part I did understand). Peace.

Comment: Can I have a TL;DR for the difference between the projections? (What actually differs)